# Stacey CMS using Markdown Extra ( special characters )

Tags: content-management-system, markdown

Has anyone tried using [Stacey CMS](http://www.staceyapp.com/) with [Markdown Extra syntax](http://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown/extra/)?  I tried using the Markdown Extra (special attributes) and the HTML class attribute syntax.  See example below.

```
## The Site ##    {.main}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work for some unusual reason.  Though, using the HTML ID attribute works.  See example below.

```
## Header 2 ##      {#header2}
```

If anyone knows how to get the HTML class attribute in Stacey CMS then please let me know.  Thanks in an advance.